# 1対多結合で多を絞り込み条件とするSQLについて

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy を使用

親テーブル
id  name
1   スズキ
2   タナカ
3   マイク
4   ルイ
5   ジャック

子テーブル
id  user_id pname   number
1   1   リンゴ 2
2   1   バナナ 1
3   1   ブドウ 3
4   2   リンゴ 2
5   2   バナナ 2
6   2   ブドウ 1
7   3   イチゴ 5
8   3   バナナ 3
9   3   ブドウ 1

リンゴを持っている親id且バナナのnumberで並べ替えしたいのですが、「リンゴを持っている親id」で検索するとフィルターされるのでバナナが消えてしまいます。実現方法を検索しても出てこきません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: どういう結果のデータが欲しいのかも記述しましょう

Comment: SQLそのものの書き方がわからないのか、SQLはわかるがそれをSQLAlchemyでどう書くのかがわからないのかどちらでしょうか